Flutter , How to form a sentence from a words that broadcasted from a websocket
Im using a websocket to make a chatbot. This is a broadcast Stream
 WebSocketHelper(@Named('webSocketUrl') String url)
      : channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(url) {
    _broadcastStream = channel.stream.asBroadcastStream();
  }

  @override
  Stream get stream => _broadcastStream;



//calling values from stream
       if (_channel != null) {
          subscription = _channel.stream.listen((message) {
            debugPrint(message)
          }, onError: (error) {
            debugPrint("stream Error $error");
          });
        }

I'm getting response if is send hi,

the response is above as follows. so what i want i need is to collect all this individual words and form a sentence. how can i do that?
